# Query a list object by a list int

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of object (with id) and a list int, what is the best way to query that list object provided the list int.

```
class CommonPartRecord {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public object Others {get;set;}
}
var listObj = new List<CommonPartRecord>();
// Load listObj
var listId = new List<int>();
// Load listId
```

Now select the listObj, for those Id is contained in listId, I currently do this way:

```
var filterItems = listObj.Where(x => listId.Contains(x.Id));
```

What would be the faster way to perform this?
Thanks,
Huy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tmpList = new HashSet<int>(listId);
var filterItems = listObj.Where(x => tmpList.Contains(x.Id));
```

This could give you a performance boost or a performance drop, it depends heavily on the size of both `listObj` and `listId`.

You will need to profile it to see if you get any improvement from it.

---

Explaining the boost or drop:

I am going to use some really exagrated numbers to make the math easier, lets say the following

- `listObj.Where(x => listId.Contains(x.Id));` takes 5 seconds per row.
- `listObj.Where(x => tmpList.Contains(x.Id))` takes 2 seconds per row.
- `var tmpList = new HashSet<int>(listId);` takes 10 seconds to build.

Lets plot out the times of how long it would take to process the data varying by the number of rows in `listObj`

```
+----------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Number of rows | Seconds to process with list | Seconds to process with hash set |
+----------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|              1 |                            5 |                               12 |
|              2 |                           10 |                               14 |
|              3 |                           15 |                               16 |
|              4 |                           20 |                               18 |
|              5 |                           25 |                               20 |
|              6 |                           30 |                               22 |
|              7 |                           35 |                               24 |
|              8 |                           40 |                               26 |
+----------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

[image]

So you can see if listObj has 1 to 3 rows your old way is faster, however once you have 4 rows or more the new way is faster.

(Note I totally made these numbers up, I can guarantee that the per row for HashSet is faster than per row for List, but I can not tell you how much faster. You will need to test to see if the point you get better performance is at 4 rows or 4,000 rows. The only way to know is try both ways and test.)